# Singleton to get a file location on Android

Tags: java, android

How can I have access to a file in my res/raw folder from a Singleton (not an activity) on Android?
I've tried:

```
InputStream is = MainActivity.getResources().openRawResource("data.json");
```

which doesn't work since "non-static method getResouces() cannot be referenced from static content".
I've also tried:

```
        URL fileURL = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(R.raw.data);
    String filePath = fileURL.getPath();
```

which throws a Null-pointer exception.

My Singleton:

```
public class CoursesDataManager {

private static CoursesDataManager instance;

private final List<Course> courses;

public static CoursesDataManager getInstance() {
    if (instance == null)
        instance = new CoursesDataManager();
    return instance;
}

private CoursesDataManager() {
    courses = parseCourses(**filePath/inputStream**);
}
```

The reason I want to get the file is that I want my Singleton to parse the data in that file once, store this data, and have this data never change and be accessible throughout the lifetime of my application.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You need context in your non activity class.

Comment: What does it mean? I can't pass any parameters to it since it is a singleton.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getResources(). Check this.

Comment: I get "non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context" error when I try to use it

Comment: getResources() is method of Context. So you require context to call getResources(). Yes its a non static method. You can use dependency injection. Check out dagger 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need context to access resources. You could use Application context for this purpose. Subclass your Application, save the context in a static variable. Use the context inside singleton.

Create a Application class:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    public static MyApplication context = null;

    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        context = this;
    }
}
```

In your manifest, specify the name of the Application class:

```
<application
        android:name=".MyApplication"
        ...
        >
</application>
```

Now, use this context in singleton:

```
InputStream is = MyApplication.context.getResources().openRawResource("data.json");
```

Note: You can use this method, even when you are creating the singleton instance from outside the Activity, where you dont have Activity context.

Answer (score 3):

```
public class CoursesDataManager {

private static CoursesDataManager instance;

private final List<String> courses;

public static CoursesDataManager getInstance(Context context) {
    if (instance == null)
        instance = new CoursesDataManager(context);
    return instance;
}

   private CoursesDataManager(Context context) {
       courses =context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.filename);

   }
}
```

call it from Activity

```
CoursesDataManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the context to your class and change it to something like that:

```
public class CoursesDataManager {

private static CoursesDataManager instance;
private Context context;

private final List<Course> courses;

public static CoursesDataManager getInstance(Context context) {
    if (instance == null)
        instance = new CoursesDataManager(context.getApplicationContext());
    return instance;
}

private CoursesDataManager(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    courses = parseCourses(**filePath/inputStream**);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class CoursesDataManager {

private static CoursesDataManager instance;
private static Context mContext;
private final List<Course> courses;

public static CoursesDataManager getInstance(Context context) {

if (instance == null)
{
    instance = new CoursesDataManager();
}
    mContext = context;
    return instance;
}

private CoursesDataManager() {
    courses = parseCourses(**filePath/inputStream**);
}
```

You can use resource from here like

```
 mContext.getResources().openRawResource(resourceId);
```